# Family tree for edible plants?

Tags: botany, taxonomy, phylogenetics, ethnobiology

I am looking for a `family tree` for plants, particularly veg / herbs / fruit.

Something similar to: [image]

If it could be slightly less technical than all the Latin names too :). The aim is to easily find out what plants are related such as Cabbage, Broccoli, sprouts, Cauliflower (all Brassicaceae). Currently having to look them all up on Wikipedia which is quite painful.

Another example, but a plant version. [image]

Comment: By a Family tree, do you mean a phylogenetic tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogenetic_tree) or a "classification" tree?

Comment: I very much doubt that you will find any sort of family tree for edible plants, because a plant that is edible may be closely related to another that is poisonous.  The common example is the Solonaceae family https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae which contains familiar foods such as potatos, tomatos, and peppers,  along with datura, mandrake, and deadly nightshade.  Indeed, some parts of plants may be edible while others are poisonous, as with potatos and the aboveground parts of the plant.

Comment: A tree of edible and non-edible would be the complete tree. Remove some elements and you have a partial tree, of edible plants. The accepted answer has already covered this, but thanks all the same!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically just search "thing you want" and "phylogeny" and you'll find a million results on Google.  For you, I might recommend the [Botanist in the Kitchen blog](http://botanistinthekitchen.wordpress.com/), which has a [whole page on the subject](http://botanistinthekitchen.wordpress.com/the-plant-food-tree-of-life/phylogenetic-tree-view/) and has assembled this phylogeny, including many, many others.  It's pretty impressive!

[image: Plant food phylogeny]

Comment: Yes, it is definetely the best solution. For detailed information concerning the phylogeny of any taxon, the best website to my knowledge is http://tolweb.org/tree/ but it will not be good looking like any picture you wil find with a simple google search. There is also this site http://www.onezoom.org/ but I am not sure it is complete.

Comment: I hadn't heard of http://onezoom.org before, that's pretty neat.

Comment: +1 for bringing my attention to Botanist in the Kitchen – what a great site!

Comment: Thanks, I think this is pretty much what I am looking for. Botanist in the kitchen is great too. onezoom.org seems good but have not found a plant section as yet.

Comment: Beware that tolweb is not very accurate: from what I understood, they lack the funding necessary to update it. So it doesn't reflect the state of the art in terms of phylogeny.